# Sorting key-value pairs with keys containg different values

Tags: c#, .net, list, key-value

I am working in .net 2.0 c#

I have a set of keys/values which I'm reading from file. So the keys may be same but with different values associated with each of them.

I want to list keys in the sorted order and show it in grid with associated values in columns as much as different values  . What can I do ? I tried with SortedList class but it does not allow duplicate keys.

in .net 3.0 linq works but i need to do it in .net 2.0.

How can I do it?

Comment: Implement an `IComparer`. [See here for a tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42839/Sorting-Lists-using-IComparable-and-IComparer-Inte).

Comment: As a sidenote: You can use most C# 3.0 features while targetting .net 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us the address the issues you pointed out in 2 parts :
[a] Issue of having same keys but with different values [Soln] Deisgn a userdefined class i.e DataKeys in the below code snippet.
[b] Ordering the Keys in the list [Soln] Implementing IComperable for the user defined class.

Below is the sample class which you could implement :

```
    internal class DataKeys : IComparable<DataKeys>
    {
        private int key;

        private string values;

        public DataKeys(int key, string values)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.values = values;
        }

        internal int Key
        {
            get { return key; }
        }

        internal string Values
        {
            get { return Values; }
        }

        public int CompareTo(DataKeys other)
        {
            if (this.key > other.key) return 1;
            else if (this.key < other.key) return -1;
            else return 0;
        }

    }
```

Just to check how this code would execute based on sample client code :

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DataKeys> dataRepository = new List<DataKeys>()
                                            {
                                                new DataKeys(10, "Key-10"),
                                                new DataKeys(11, "Key-11"),
                                                new DataKeys(9, "Key-9"),
                                                new DataKeys(8, "Key-8"),
                                                new DataKeys(100, "Key-100")
                                            };
        dataRepository.Sort();

        foreach (var dataKeyse in dataRepository)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataKeyse.Key);
        }
    }
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DataTable` in your scenario:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("TextFile.txt");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("key");
        dt.Columns.Add("value");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string key = line.Split(',')[0];
            string value = line.Split(',')[1];
            dt.Rows.Add(key, value);
        }
        dt.DefaultView.Sort="key";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

The `TextFile.txt` text file:

```
1,test1
2,test2
3,test3
2,test4
1,test5
1,test6
```

Comment: i am doing it in .net 2.0, is there var available

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: I've updated the answer by replacing the usage of `var` with explicit types.

Comment: hi, i made a list<string,string> anf fill it with values, now i want to compare it using my first string and sort. i used sort(), but it gives exception" invalid operation exception". how can i do it

Comment: Have you used my example? Is it working for you? What is a `list<string,string>`?

Comment: i meant " List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>"